# ajax get not received by servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am brand new to jQuery and $Ajax() but quite familiar with Java EE, and totally stuck on this.

I have a js function and info from the javascript console in firebug that it sends a request to the servlet - but the message never arrives to the servlet.

When get or post reaches the servlet it will always log something, but it never logs anything when "called" by $Ajax().

Here is the some of the output from fireBug:

```
about to call ajax()<br>
showCID.jsp (line 12)<br>

    GET http://localhost:8080/RHY_Tools/AjaxServlet?id=123<br>

jquery....min.js (line 6)<br>
done with call to ajax()<br>
showCID.jsp (line 41)  Error:<br>
showCID.jsp (line 30)  Status: error<br>
showCID.jsp (line 31)  readyState <br>
```

There is nothing in the log from the server.

If I paste

```
    http://localhost:8080/RHY_Tools/AjaxServlet?id=123 into the browser window the server log shows:

INFO: Id parameter is: 123<br>
INFO: done now.<br>
```

Here is the function (and the log above shows it is called)

```
var myurl="AjaxServlet";
function checkCID(cid) {

console.log("about to call ajax()");

$.ajax({
    url:myurl ,
    data: {id: 123},
    type: "GET",

    success: function( resp ) {
        $( "" ).text( resp ).appendTo( "body" );
    },

    error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
        console.log( "Status: " + status );
        console.dir( xhr );
    },

    complete: function( xhr, status ) {
        alert( "The request is complete!" );
    }
});

console.log("done with call to ajax()");
}
```

Comment: Can you open up your browser's network console and see what the response contains?

Comment: Can you log resp before adding it to body via this line $( "" ).text( resp ).appendTo( "body" ); console.log( "Response: " + resp );

Comment: 1)  There is no network traffic from the $Ajax() call!  2) there is no way to look at resp because the success: clause is never reached.  I have added the console.log (but it does nothing).

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- the url shouldn't need the full host (since it's ajax it goes to what the browser is already connected to by default). Did you try myurl = '/RHY_Tools/AjaxServlet?id=123' ?
- check the network traffic panel from firebug and see whether from the client perspective it gets a response (404, 500, 200, etc), or simply times out. That should help you debug where it's actually reaching, if anywhere
- Lastly, and this might just have been a typo in the post/html above, but I see the URL had "
  " at the end?

Comment: I just name the servlet "AjaxServlet"  - the log shows an entry from jQuery with the correct complete url.  I have run this 100 times with various variations - One time it worked - then stopped working with zero changes to the deployment.  From that I can see what a response would look like - it seems that jQuery is throwing an error BEFORE calling the servlet.  Because otherwise firebug shows NO NETOWRK traffic from that call. But there is nothing readable in the error message which reads "error"

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by cross origin script. Where is your HTML and JavaScript located? On the same server as your servlet? On another server? Or on your local disk?

If in browser you open am HTML file directly from the file system and then in the script attempt to call the server, then this is problem. Your script attempts to access a server that is different from the origin of your script.

In such case browser normally asks the server if it will accept a request from another source and if server confirms that only then sends the browser the request to the server.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing.

Solution alternatives:

1. Put your HTML and JavaScript to the same server as your servlet.
2. Or, on the server, add a handler that sets corresponding headers. That will signal the browser that it will accept requests from another origin.

Comment: The servlet and the jsp containing the Ajax() are on the same server in the same application.  Firebug console shows a log entry from jQuery's whcih the fully expanded address which is correct - and works when pasted into the browser.  It seems that Ajax() is not not actually making the request - it is failing before making the request.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.  I was asking the wrong question so you could not give the right answer.

This had nothing to do with the call to $Ajax() nor the servlet, etc.

It was because of the way I was calling the function as a onChange() event in text field in an HTML form.  I don't yet understand the details of how that caused the symptoms - somehow the script ran to completion but Ajax failed -  but if I call the exact same function to the exact same servlet - but in a different way within the HTML form all is well.